# to deal with matters related with insurance

Tags: meaning, infinitives, ambiguity

a. We have an accountant in our company to deal with matters related to insurance.

b. In our company, we have an accountant to deal with matters related to insurance.

c. We have an accountant to deal with matters related to insurance in our company.

==========================================

Do any of these imply that we have only one accountant in our company?

Do any of them imply that the accountant in question **only** deals with matters related to insurance?

Could that accountant handle all our accounting work and deal with matters related to insurance?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather say

**We have an accountant in our company who deals with insurance issues/matters**

- which could be one or many accountants
- it doesn't imply that the accountant in question only deals with insurance issues/matters

which then answers your questions:

Do any of these imply that we have only one accountant in our company?

NO

Do any of them imply that the accountant in question only deals with matters related to insurance?

NO

Could that accountant handle all our accounting work and deal with matters related to insurance?

MAYBE - if the accountant is qualified to do so

Answer (score 2):

a. *We have an accountant in our company to deal with matters related to insurance*.
b. *In our company, we have an accountant to deal with matters related to insurance*.

These both suggests s/he deals **only** with matters related to insurance. They **might** suggest you have only one accountant.

c. *We have an accountant to deal with matters related to insurance in our company*.

This says s/he deals **only** with matters related to insurance. You may have other accountants. Perhaps more importantly, the words "insurance in our company" might be understood as "insurance within our company". If the insurance concerns other companies or individuals, c is misleading.
To make it clear that you have more than one accountant, you could say:

d. *Matters related to insurance are dealt with by one of our accountants*.
or:
e. *Insurance matters are dealt with by one of our company accountants*.

Btw, you might consider saying, "...*one of our in-house accountants*."